# How to use gcc and -msoft-float on an i386/x86-64?

Tags: gcc, g++, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using software floating point on x86 linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018638/using-software-floating-point-on-x86-linux)

Just for educational reasons I'd like to compile some programmes using the `-msoft-float` option of `gcc`, i.e. doing floating point arithmetic without using the x87/sse fpu unit. Take a simple example:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   double x=3.14;
   double y=2.71;
   double z=x+y;
   printf("z=%f\n",z);
   return 0;
}
```

Compile with either (need to disable sse otherwise `-msoft-float` has no effect)

```
g++ -msoft-float -mfpmath=387 float.cpp
g++ -msoft-float -m32 float.cpp
```

and I get

```
float.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `__adddf3'
```

Now the man page warns me that I might need to provide my own soft-float library. However, since I'm not doing cross-compilation, does this still apply?

```
   -msoft-float
       Generate output containing library calls for floating point.
       Warning: the requisite libraries are not part of GCC.  Normally the
       facilities of the machine's usual C compiler are used, but this
       can't be done directly in cross-compilation.  You must make your own
       arrangements to provide suitable library functions for cross-
       compilation.
```

I checked `libgcc_s.so` as well as other libraries and `__adddf3` is indeed nowhere to be found. I also looked into the `gcc-4.6.2` source code and there's a directory
`./gcc/config/soft-fp/` with all the soft-float routines, but I failed to compile them by hand.

So is there a way to just compile a soft-float library (or do I have to compile a whole new gcc) or have I overseen something more simple?

Comment: Great question, but this has been covered before.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the duplicate. There seems to be a quick solution by manually compiling the contents of `libgcc/soft-fp/` into a library. I've added it to the [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018638/using-software-floating-point-on-x86-linux).

Comment: Thanks :) And no worries, some stuff is just hard to search for.