# Soft Float on x86_64

Tags: gcc, clang, cross-compiling

I work on software for an embedded system which does not have an FPU. I would like to be able to build this software with a software floating point library on my desktop in order to get a more realistic view of performance. Does anyone have any ideas about how to achieve this?

Thus far I have not made much progress with using `-msoft-float` with gcc. I am currently looking at using clang. By using the flags `-Xclang -msoft-float -Xclang -no-implicit-float` and specifying a library which has implementations of soft-float routines, I am able to get my application to compile. When I try to run it, it always segfaults. As best I can tell, this is because the libraries on which this program depends were not compiled with soft-float. The app depends on gtk, sqlite, expat, gcrypt, a number of internal libraries, and libc.

I would like to try to figure out how to build a complete build environment with soft-float support. I tried uclibc's buildroot and setting `CC` and `CXX` to clang's binaries, but this did not work due to the requirements for compiling the gcc toolchain (things such as autotools complaining about the compiler version being incorrect). Since I would like to use clang as the compiler in the new buildroot (in order to have soft-float support), I don't see a pressing need to build gcc. Is it possible to do this without gcc?

Comment: I think this is impossible without changing the code, because the `x86_64` ABI requires `xmm` registers to be present. Maybe some `-Ddouble=mpfr::real` trickery will work, using the `mpfr` library which is required by `gcc` anyway.

Comment: As noted, `clang` was able to compile a binary with no references to the floating point instructions or registers. I suppose my real question therefore is if there is a way to make a whole toolchain using something like this.

Comment: Was the proposed solution ok?

Comment: I have not had opportunity to try it yet, unfortunately. I fear it is going to result in the same set of problems I ran into before when trying to use the `-msoft-float` option with GCC: 1. Errors about an x87 register return when x87 instructions are disabled. 2. Undefined symbols for the floating point operations when trying to compile a cross toolchain and no indication of what to change to link properly. I will award the bounty because you definitely put some effort behind the answer.

Comment: Have a look at [compiler_rt](http://compiler-rt.llvm.org/) project.

Answer (score 6):

GCC can not do it out-of-box without some additional libraries. Basically, `-msoft-float` just generate calls for floating point libraries but the required libraries are not part of GCC.

To link the `soft-fp` libraries you can use the switch `-lsoft-fp`.

X86_64 architecture contains SSE extensions, so the compiler will try to generate SSE-code for basic operations like + - * /. We will use `-mno-sse` switch suppress this unauthorized behavior.

It may look as follows:

```
gcc -g -msoft-float -mno-sse -m64 -lsoft-fp
```

For the code:

```
int main()
{
    float a = 10;
    float b = 20;

    float c = a * b;

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting assembly will be:

```
    .file   "12.cpp"
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    __mulsf3;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 48
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    movl    .LC0(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    .LC1(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -8(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
    call    __mulsf3
    movl    %eax, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section .rdata,"dr"
    .align 4
.LC0:
    .long   1092616192
    .align 4
.LC1:
    .long   1101004800
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.0 20120624 (experimental)"
```

No SSE instructions were generated. Note the call to `__mulsf3`.

Some interesting ideas can be found in this question: [Using software floating point on x86 linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1018638/1065190)

Comment: I doubt this will work - for library calls this is ok, but the basic operations like `+ - * /` will still be SSE/xmm, because there is no x86_64 without SSE

Comment: You are right about SSE. But it will work. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: If I try to compile this with gcc-4.7.2 I get an `error: SSE register return with SSE disabled`, maybe 4.8 is required?

Comment: If you say so... I have 4.8 "Experimental".

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55302926/1569204) suggests the ABI does not allow it. Either this one or that one must be at least incomplete?