# software floating point and x87 or sse disabled

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point

I am trying to enable software floating point under gcc following suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018638/using-software-floating-point-on-x86-linux) but I've hit a snag:

The -msoft-float flag causes:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h: In function ‘long double std::stold(const string&, std::size_t*)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2857:47: error: x87 register return with x87 disabled
   stold(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0)
                                               ^
```

and -mno-sse causes:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h: In function ‘float std::stof(const string&, std::size_t*)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/basic_string.h:2849:46: error: SSE register return with SSE disabled
   stof(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0)
                                              ^
```

There are a [couple of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556142/sse-register-return-with-sse-disabled) which mention this error but in relation to kernel programming which doesn't help.

All that is happening in basic_string is the functions are returning floats or doubles. Why does this cause a compilation failure?

More importantly, what can I do about it?

### Background

I have found a difference in behaviour for a C++ application on two different platforms:

- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5504
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU

Code compiled natively on either machine runs on the other but
for one test the behaviour depends on which machine the code is run on.

**Clarification**
*The executable compiled on machine A behaves like the executable compiled on machine B when copied to run on machnie B and visa versa.*

It could an uninitialised variable or many other things but
I suspect that the cause could be non-portable use of floating point.
Perhaps one machine is interpreting the float point assembly differently from the other?
I want to test my hypothesis.
I thought if I could force the program to use (ideally strict IEE 754) software floating point it might confirm or rule that out.
Its not my code and I have no desire to completely rewrite it to test this. Recompiling is fine though.

Related to this I have asked a separate question [how-to-detect-differences-in-floating-point-behaviour-across-platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55300378/1569204) tackling the question from the other side.

Comment: Try compiling with `-ffp-mode=full` or `-fno-fast-math`.  That should force strict IEEE754 conformance.

Comment: I tried -fno-fast-math but it made no obvious difference. There is no -ffp-mode option in gcc 4.8 on my platform. I think that may be specific to another compiler or platform.

Comment: I have another wacky idea relating to this see [emulator-to-run-an-application-as-if-its-on-a-different-cpu](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/56933/emulator-to-run-an-application-as-if-its-on-a-different-cpu)

Answer (score 2):

"Why does this cause a compilation failure?"

Because the relevant ABI (x87/x64) are defined to return a `float` value in a hardware float register. You obviously need hardware floating point to have that register.

"More importantly, what can I do about it?"

Not much. Unlike x87/x64, ARM does have a soft-FP ABI, so `-msoft-float` does work there, and that's the main reason GCC still has soft FP.

Comment: Not much I can say to that except "Oh crud!". Sometimes the right answer isn't the answer you want to hear. Thanks :)

Comment: Hang on a minute - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201495/soft-float-on-x86-64 suggests that is possible. It has bounty reward but the answer is not accepted. Either this answer or that answer is incomplete.

Comment: If this is forbidden why allow the -msoft-float at all on x86_64. Likewise what could -mno-sse be used for if it breaks the ABI?
Why doens't -msoft-float cause the register to be replaced with a structure (or width enough integer type if there is one)? I guess the problem is deciding a link time which representation to pass (e..g for linking to external libraries_. Is there a place for that information live in the ELF object?

Comment: @BruceAdams: Because if you don't actually call methods across Translation Unit boundaries, the ABI doesn't matter that much. And if you use FP purely within a single function, then the ABI does not matter at all. ABI's are for linkers.

Comment: In this case my code is failing to compile because the basic_string header declares strtof and strol but those functions are not used anywhere in the code. They are of course provided by libstdc++ though. I would be happy for -msoft-float to only apply within the translation unit. In fact that is exactly what I wanted and expected.

Comment: In c++ using std::string is hard to avoid so I can't easily isolate things even if it was my code.